# Must have even number of URI's. - XSD Schema - XML Doc

Tags: xml, xsd

The error is:

> SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = 'E:\SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd' must
>   have even number of URI's.

I am a complete noob regarding XSD.   I have managed to create a SEPA payment format.. but am falling over with the schema part of the header.

I created a schema using the ff website... saved it to E:\ drive  so the file and location is '**E:\SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd**'

This is my schema header on line 2 of the XML:

```
<S2SCTIcf:SCTIcfBlkCredTrf 
  xmlns:S2SCTIcf="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="E:\SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd">
```

I hope you can help this noggin.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The xsi:schemaLocation attribute takes a list of URI pairs, where the first member of each pair is a namespace name and the second identifies the location of an XSD schema document for that namespace.

If the target namespace of your schema document is (as it appears to be) `urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf`, then you need to write

```
schemaLocation="urn:S2SCTIcf:xsd:$SCTIcfBlkCredTrf
                file:///E:/SCTIcfBlkCredTrf.xsd"
```

or the equivalent.

Comment: Thanks.. This helped me understand this element.  The Target was incorrect. With your help I progressed to the next step.

However, another issue popped up..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20654310/cvc-elt-1-cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-s2scticfscticfblkcredtrf